# Create a table in a new database and insert values from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new table in a database and trying to copy a database with all properties and values from a different table in a different database.

I am using following query

```
Use Hello
Go

Create Table AR
as
    Select * 
    from G.dbo.AcctsRec
```

But I get an error at Select

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

It had more than 15 columns. Not my creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
INTO Hello.dbo.AR 
FROM G.dbo.AcctsRec
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use select * into syntax

```
select * into AR from dbo.AcctsRec
```

Comment: without declaring databases? Both tables are in different DBs. I ran it and it is giving me following error Invalid object name 'dbo.AcctsRec'.

Comment: You can use databases like "G.dbo.AcctsRec"

Comment: Sometimes the constraints you have used for instance in AcctsRec table will be removed if you use into statement and create a new table which AR this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AR')
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO dbo.AR
  FROM G.dbo.AcctsRec
  WHERE 1 = 0 --This means you can Create Table Structure with out Data 

END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AR')
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO dbo.AR
  FROM G.dbo.AcctsRec
  WHERE 1 = 1 --This means you can Create Table Structure Including Data 

END
```